# how to download and install ubuntu in andriod phones?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

I am using sony erricson xperia ray mobile phone. I heard that Ubuntu is available for smart phones. Is it possible to install ubuntu in my phone? I am very eager to try ubuntu in my phone. if it is possible where could I downald and install in my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, ubuntu phone targets developers only. There is a lot of functionality missing or uncompleted. Don't get me wrong, they have done a great work for a first beta, but the OS is still far to be used as main phone OS.

If you want it for test purpose, it is available here : http://www.ubuntu.com/phone
But there is no official version for the moment for Sony Erricson, only for Nexus devices.
If you look a bit through the web, you may be able to find a way to install it on your device.

Answer (score -1):

The XDA forums may be your best place to start:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch

If it's available, you'll likely find it there.

Comment: If you are just forwarding a link it is normally best to just leave a comment. It is not really a full "answer".